# How to prevent the value to not exceed 5 chars?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that adds value on click. It adds 5.99 on click. However, sometimes it equals to very long numbers. I want to prevent it and make it maximum 5 chars.

```
<div id="tutar">0</div>
```

js

```
$("#tutar").text((+$("#tutar").text()+5.99));
```

So I Tried this

```
$("#tutar").text((+$("#tutar").text()+5.99).substring(0,5));
```

Without any luck. What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: Do you want to round or truncate? What if the value is invalid (like a string)?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this?

Comment: @MathiasBecher Its a shopping card value. And you know, seeing a price like $19.0000028 doesnt look cool.

Comment: @Tony I want to truncate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method and pass the number to appear after decimal.

```
$("#tutar").text((+$("#tutar").text()+5.99).toFixed(2));
```

e.g. `2.55555` will become `2.56`

Comment: Clearest and smartest way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

First do addition, convert it to string and then use `substring` (as you are worried about chars only not decimal places).

```
$("#tutar").text((parseFloat($("#tutar").text())+5.99).toString().substring(0, 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#tutar").html( ( parseFloat( $("#tutar").html() ) + 5.99 ).substring( 0, 5 ) );
```

get rid of the additional `+` in the beginning. Also use `parseFloat` to make sure that value that you are adding to is an integer at first place.